# R - Difference between calling value vs value()

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

Why should you call df() instead of df in the code below? Is this the correct syntax to use with the reactive function?

```
function(input, output, session){
  df <- reactive({
    head(cars, input$nrows)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(df()) #Why call df() instead of df?
  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    df() #Why call df() instead of df?
  })
}
```

Comment: So I'm not sure how involved an explanation you need. The function `reactive` returns a function. So `foo <- reactive({...})` is creating a function `foo()` based on the expression you give it. That's why it has to be called as a function. Deeper "why" answers would probably delve into how the only way to get the reactive behavior is via a function...

Comment: @joran That makes sense now. I did not know that reactive returns a function. Thanks for your explaination!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the value of `df` to equal the return value from a call to `reactive`.

From `?reactive`:

> **Value**
>
> a function, wrapped in a S3 class "reactive"

`df`, therefore, is a function which, when called, will evaluate the saved expression and return the current value (and also trigger updates reactively).